# Which sample size and number of independent variables to use for adjusted R squared?

Tags: machine-learning, measurement-error

Bellow is a formula for estimation of adjusted R squared from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2):

[image]

where `p` is the number of independent variables and `n` is a sample size.

I want to get adjusted R squared for machine learning prediction model estimated on a test set. I am estimating R squared of the model and now I need to convert it to the adjusted R squared.

**My question is:** If I am estimating the adjusted R squared of the model on the test set, should I use `n` and `p` of the test set or the train set?

Answer (score 4):

Adjusted $R^2$ is for the same sample/sub-sample on which $R^2$ was obtained. So if the $R^2$ is from the test set, then the n and p are from the test set as well. $R^2$ and Adjusted $R^2$ are measures of **in-sample model fit**. The adjustment is for the fact that the addition of another regressor will never result in a lower $R^2$; on the other hand, the addition of another regressor will increase adjusted $R^2$ only if doing so reduces the residual mean square.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So to clarify, in this case it does not matter that model was actually was trained on the train set, right?